# How can I keep track of the number of epochs completed while training a Word2Vec model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I'm training my Word2Vec model for more than 12 hours for a corpus of more than 90k tweets (samples), ~10k unique words in the dictionary for a number of 5 epochs with my 8gb RAM laptop. Is it normal?

I want to track the progress of the training process which is why I want to keep track of the number of epochs completed while training. How can I do that? My code given below:

```
model = Word2Vec(df['tweet_text'], window=10, vector_size=300, hs=0, negative=1) 
model.train([df['tweet_text']], total_examples=len(df['tweet_text']), epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweets are usually only a dozen to a few dozen word-tokens, so "90k tweets" are probably only around 2-3 million words, total.

That's on the small side for training a `Word2Vec` model, which benefits from plentiful data. But it also shouldn't take 12 hours, so something else is likely going wrong.

One key technique to gt more information on the progress of Gensim code is to enable Python logging to at least the `INFO` level. This can be done either globally, or for certain classes/modules. (It can also be set to the `DEBUG` level for even more detail.)

When I'm doing the initial work on something, I *always* enable `INFO` logging globally to get a better view of what's going on. Only when later re-running well-debugged code might I potentially disable logging, or narrow it to fewer classes/levels.

Here's a simple bit of boilerplate for turning on `INFO` logging at Python's 'root' logger (global logging):

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', 
                    level=logging.INFO)
```

Once on, you'll see reports about how many words have been discovered or retained in the model, and when epochs begin and end – which covers your explicit request here. Thus, you'll get a vague idea of whether progress is happening, and at what rate – giving you a rough idea of how much remains to be done.

Over time, from watching the logging, you'll also notice other hints of whether a step has done what you intended – showing sensible internal interim counts, after a reasonable amount of time – or has somehow gone wrong, showing bad counts, or steps that complete instantly even though they genuinely should've taken longer, or steps that get hung.

I'm not sure why you don't have results after 12 hours, but a few other comments on potential problems with your code as currently shown:

- Does `df['tweet_text']` truly return what `Word2Vec` needs as a corpus? `Word2Vec` needs a re-iterable Python sequence object that, when other code wants to iterate-over it, returns individual items that are each a Python `list`, with every item in that `list` a string word-token. (If you are supplying plain strings that haven't already been tokenized into lists-of-words, it won't see the words you intend.)
- `negative=1` is a very atypical setting, far from the default `negative=5`. (It might be OK if you had a giant corpus – which you don't. In my experience, it's more common for projects with less training data, and in a hurry, to try *larger* `negative` values, like `negative=10` or `negative=20`. But at your level of data & expertise, `negative` isn't a parameter you should likely be tinkering with at all, yet.)
- You *may* pass your training data into the object-constructor, as you'v done in your code. But if you do that, the model will do all necessary steps on that corpus automatically. That is, it does its own `.build_vocab()` step internally, then its own `.train()` step – and you have a trained model after the model-constructor returns. You then *don't* need to call `.train()` yourself, like you've done here. It's redundant. If you copied this from some online example – the provider of that example didn't know what they were doing. Don't learn any other bad habits from them! (Alternatively, you can leave your corpus out of the constructor, so it returns a minimally-initialized model immediately, then call `.build_vocab()` and `.train()` yourself, supplying your data.)
- Larger vectors like `vector_size=300` also require lots of training data to reach sufficient quality. If you're using a relatively smaller corpus, as you are, you'll likely get better vectors using a smaller size - such as the class's default `vector_size=100`, or sometimes even smaller. So again, your code has changed things from the default, probably for the worse. (This may be the case with choosing `window=10`, too. That's the sort of change it's bettr to make only when you have evidence it will improve things on your end goals, *not* as a random guess.)

When you add logging, and verify that `df['tweet_text']` is of the right format, and avoid redundant steps and unjustified alterations to defaults, you may see what's going wrong right away. Or at least, you'll be able to ask a new question, with more info, about whatever is the problem them.